# How to programmatically set a localStorage with increasing values?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want a localStorage to be programmatically defined. I have an array of values in it Just want the localStorage to take it and define new storage. Like if a click a button it should define a localStorage as 'session 0' with the value from the array and If I click it the second time it should define another localStorage as 'session 1'. But after I close the window and open it and click the button the new localStorage should be continued like 'session 2' not start over from 0.

And it should check if the previous localStorage does have a value or not. Like if I am defining 'session 3' it should check if 'session 2' exists and have a value.

But what problem I am overcoming is after I close the window and start the process the localStorage doesn't start off from where it left if starts from 0 and redefines the storage that was declared first.

Fakearr consists of the value.

This is what I have tried.

```
for (let i = 0; i <= fakearr.length; i++) {
                        if (
                            (localStorage.getItem(`session ${i}`) == null &&
                                localStorage.getItem(`session ${i - 1}`).length >= 0) ||
                            localStorage.length == 0
                        ) {
                            localStorage.setItem(`session ${i}`, JSON.stringify(fakearr[i]));
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: What is the value returned if you call `localStorage.getItem` before your loop? Does your `session 0` item ever get set/is it set on load?

Comment: @Tom no session0 in never set on load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```js
function maxSessionID(){
    let i = 0;
    while (localStorage.getItem(`session${i}`) !== null ) {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

for (let i = 0; i < fakearr.length; i++) {
    localStorage.setItem(`session${maxSessionID()+1}`, JSON.stringify.fakearr[i]);
}
```

There is check for highest ID number `sessionID` before adding each item from `fakearr` so this doesn't replace existing sessions when there is hole in IDs (in case of `session0`, `session2`, `session3`. It adds `session1` and then continues from `session4`)

Comment: What happens is when the maxSessionID() is called the existing for loop breaks and it starts from 0. So it assigns all elements in fakearr repeatedly. So if session0 equals fakearr[0] then what it does is break the loop. So the next time sessionID() is called session0 = fakearr[0], session 1 = fakearr[0] and then session2 = fakearr[1]. This is what happens.

Comment: maxSessionID just returns max ID from session in continuous row from 0. You can put this  check before the loop then any value after "hole" will be re-defined. Or maybe you have to add some additional checks.